# Functional equation:$f(f(x+y))=f(x)+f(y)$

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

> find all continous functions$$f(f(x+y))=f(x)+f(y)$$

My try:setting $y=0$
$$f(f(x))=f(x)+k$$ where $k=f(0)$

hence:let $f(x)=t$,$$f(t)=t+k$$
alternatively:$$f(x)=x+C$$

My question:1)Have i got all solutions?I think i am missing a generalised one.

2)does the word continous mean any thing important. I mean if they had not mentioned will there be more functions?